# HTTP2C (cleartext) client to HTTP2C server

Tags: http2

I have an HTTP2C Embedded Jetty 9.x Server running ... note the server connector shows h2c ...

```
2016-03-21 09:25:44.082:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@66c7bd3f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c, h2c-17, h2c-16, h2c-15, h2c-14]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

I have an OkHttpClient 3 attempting to talk HTTP2C to this server , however it always gets downgraded to HTTP/1.1, what am I missing? Which Java client API supports HTTP2C? My client code is as below ...

```
package http2;

import java.util.Collections;
import okhttp3.ConnectionSpec;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

    public class GetClear {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT).build();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec)).build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://localhost:8080/test").build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println (response.body().string());
        System.out.println("****");

        response.body().close();

    }

}
```

[The server prints the 'request.getProtocol' from a Jetty servlet and that shows HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2].

HTTP/2 server and client on TLS works just fine using HTTP/2(client code and server code are different of course).

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Jetty HTTP2C client, the same server code works. I guess OkHTTPClient does not support HTTP2C.

Answer (score 1):

A complete h2c example using the `HelloHandler` example from the jetty doc:

```
public class HelloServer {
    public static class HelloHandler extends AbstractHandler {
        final String greeting;
        final String body;

        public HelloHandler() {
            this("Hello World");
        }

        public HelloHandler(String greeting) {
            this(greeting, null);
        }

        public HelloHandler(String greeting, String body) {
            this.greeting = greeting;
            this.body = body;
        }

        public void handle(String target,
                           Request baseRequest,
                           HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
                ServletException {
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            out.println("<h1>" + greeting + "</h1>");
            if (body != null) {
                out.println(body);
            }

            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.setHandler(new HelloHandler());

        HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConnectionFactory h1 = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig);
        ConnectionFactory h2c = new HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory(httpConfig);
        ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(server, h1, h2c);
        serverConnector.setPort(8080);

        server.setConnectors(new ServerConnector[] { serverConnector });
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jetty log line shows that you have configured the server connector to have HTTP/1.1 to be the default protocol (that is the upper-case "HTTP/1.1" before the brackets containing the list of protocols supported).

You don't show your server-side code, but you have two choices:

1. Configure explicitly the default protocol for the server connector:

```java
serverConnector.setDefaultProtocol("h2c");
```

2. Pass the `ConnectionFactory` objects in the right order to the server connector, since the first one will be the default protocol:

```java
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
ConnectionFactory h1 = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig);
ConnectionFactory h2c = new HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory(httpConfig);
ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(server, h2c, h1);
```

Comment: Making h2c the default will mean that ordinary HTTP/1.1 clients can no longer talk to your server.  This is almost certainly not what you want.  [The questioner's problem was just using a client that doesn't talk HTTP/2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341210/394431)

Comment: @RobertTupelo-Schneck so you make a comment 3 years after this response, linking an answer from the OP that was made 10 days after I wrote mine, and without the OP originally saying those details in the original question. Thanks for your comment. Oh, turns out that 3 years later, OkHttp does support `h2c`.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wrote that comment because I encountered this question when researching how to configure h2c in Jetty, and yours was then the top-voted answer.    Written by a Jetty maintainer no less, it seemed likely to be canonical!  But after further work it turned out to be a red herring, and again, is probably not what other readers want to do.  My hope was that my comment would save future effort from others.  Questions and answers on StackOverflow are intended to be used and useful for many years---I don't know if you intended sarcasm, but if so, I suggest it is out of place.